# radio button choice not posting in the MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image]I am posting some data into a mysql database using soome html and php. I am having some difficulty to post the radio. I think I am messing up the way I am declaring it in my php and in the database. I have defined the radio as tinyint. This is my php

```
$value = $_POST['name'];
$value2 = $_POST['email'];
$value3 = $_POST['address'];
$value4 = $_POST['city'];
$value5 = $_POST['state'];
$value6 = $_POST['zip'];
$value7 = $_POST['primary'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (name, email, address, city, state, zip, primary) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6', '$value7')";
```

html

```
<div id="options">
        <div class="opt1"><input type="radio" name="primary" value="Color" /></div>
        <div class="opt2"><input type="radio" name="primary" value="Dry" /></div>
        <div class="opt3"><input type="radio" name="primary" value="Damaged" /></div>
        <div class="opt4"><input type="radio" name="primary" value="Thinning" /></div>
    </div>
```

I have other form elements as text fields and they are going though

Comment: SQL Injection. SQL Injection. <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is (I believe) caused by using `intval()`.

The value you are passing is a string - either Color, Dry, Damaged, or Thinning.

If you want to pass an integer to `$value7` - change the values of your radio buttons in the html to the desired result.

eg:
`<div class="opt1"><input type="radio" name="primary" value="1" /></div>`

Comment: @anwyatt- Actually i would like to post the string. Thanks for catching that. I changed the $value7 to this $value7 = $_POST['primary']); and type as varchar in the mysql..but its still not going through

Comment: @soum Is it inserting the row, and just leaving the 'primary' field blank? Have you tried running a var_dump or print_r on $_POST to see if there is a value being sent to $_POST['primary']?

Comment: @anwyatt- i added an image how it actually looks like. When I am adding that radio no row is added.

Comment: @soum did you check to make sure that $value7 and $_POST['primary'] have values - either by echo-ing them or doing a print_r or var_dump? like var_dump($_POST);?

Comment: @soum - also try printing your query to the screen - see what it looks like.

Comment: actually I pretty new to this so I am having a hard time following what you are asking me to do. I tried to load my php page and got this message. If this tells anything
Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'primary) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '', '')' at line 1

Comment: It looks like your variables have no values assigned to them. Insert this at the top of the page, submit your form, and show me what the output is: print_r($_POST);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27519/discussion-between-anwyatt-and-soum)

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons and checkboxes are passed to the post as Arrays. You need to change names of all the radio buttons. `<input type="radio" name="primary[]" value="Color" />` and the same for Dry, Damaged and Thinning. And also in your PHP: $value7 = $_POST['primary'][0];

Answer (score 0):

How did you define your database table ? If you are storing it as integer, then you should be passing in the value rather than text. If you are saving the string value of the radio button, then what you are doing might not work,

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/051e29/insert-value-from-radio-button-in-mysql-in-php/

Check out this article and hope this works out for you.